# Windows Phone 8.1 MenufFyout acting up(bug?)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to have a MenuFlyout on every item of a ListView. This work's so far without a problem in the way i want it to. But there's one thing that never get solved no matter how much i try. No matter what property i set, the MenuFlyout always clamps to the right side of the screen. i've checked every link with documentation and questions in regards of Windows Phone 8.1 applications using  this but without luck. Here's some of the code.

```
<StackPanel>
    <AppBarButton Icon="More" 
                  ClickMode="Release" 
                  Foreground="Black" 
                  IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" 
                  IsHoldingEnabled="False" 
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right">

        <AppBarButton.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="25,0,25,25"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </MenuFlyout.MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </MenuFlyout>
        </AppBarButton.Flyout>
        <AppBarButton.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="90" TranslateX="0" TranslateY="0"/>
        </AppBarButton.RenderTransform>
    </AppBarButton>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: If in the AppBarButton you set HorizontalAligment="Left" the button appears on the left size of the Screen and the Flyout above it? In W10 Desktop & Phone appears fine

Comment: The thing is, i want my AppBarButton to be on the right side of the item in top right of the ListViewItem. But i will look into that in a moment. My team managed whole project to crash due to a sqlite import which causes the xaml files to give errors like page is not supported in a Windows Phone project and it crashes from time to time so i need to fix that first @JuanPabloGarciaCoello